# Is it possible to have a single ingress resource for all mulesoft applications in RTF in Self Managed Kubernetes on AWS?

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-ec2, kubernetes-ingress, mule4

Can we have a single ingress resource for deployment of all mulesoft applications in RTF in Self Managed Kubernetes on AWS?

Ingress template:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: rtf-ingress
  namespace: rtf 
  annotations:
     nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
      rewrite ^/app-name(/|$)(.*) /$2 break;
     nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
     nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
     nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/enable-underscores-in-headers: "true"
     nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
spec:
  ingressClassName: rtf-nginx 
   
  rules:
  - host: example.com
    http:
      paths: 
      - pathType: Prefix
        path: /
        backend: 
          service:
           name: temp1-svc
           port:
             number: 80
       - pathType: Prefix
         path: /
         backend: 
         service:
           name: temp2-svc
           port:
             number: 80
```

temp1-svc:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: temp1-svc
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 80
    protocol: TCP
    name: http
  selector:
    app: temp1-svc
```

temp2-svc:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: temp2-svc
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 80
    protocol: TCP
    name: http
  selector:
    app: temp2-svc
```

I am new to RTF, any changes to be done in Ingress resource or do we need to have separate ingress resource for each application? Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Generally managing different, **ingress** if good option.

You can also use the **single ingress** routing and forwarding traffic across the cluster.

**Single ingress for all services**

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: rtf-ingress
  namespace: rtf 
  annotations:
     nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
      rewrite ^/app-name(/|$)(.*) /$2 break;
     nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
     nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
     nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/enable-underscores-in-headers: "true"
     nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
spec:
  ingressClassName: rtf-nginx 
   
  rules:
  - host: example.com
    http:
      paths: 
      - pathType: ImplementationSpecific
        path: /(.*)
        backend: 
          service:
            name: service
            port:
              number: 80
      - pathType: ImplementationSpecific
        path: /(.*)
        backend: 
          service:
            name: service-2
            port:
              number: 80
```

the benefit of multiple ingress resources or separate ingress is that you can keep and configure the different **annotations** to your ingress.

In one, you want to enable **CORS** while in another you want to change proxy body head etc. So it's better to manage ingress for each microservice.

Comment: Thanks @Harsh. I have created with 2 different services but I am not getting proper response for 2 applications. Response in Postman: "No listener for endpoint: /base-api/v1/temp2" (404 Not found) and same for application-1. Could you please let me know where am I going wrong? I have edited the question with service yaml files.